# How to save your project to Azure DevOps from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, azure-repos

I am new to Visual Studio and Azure DevOps. I have created an ASP.NET and C# project on Visual Studio, and now I want to save it to an Azure DevOps repository. This repo exists and I have access to it.

How do I save this project to that repo from within Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Navigate to the Push view in Team Explorer by choosing the Visual Studio Unpublished Changes Status Bar icon in the status bar [image]. You can also select Sync from the Home view in Team Explorer.
2. In the Push view in Team Explorer, select the Publish Git Repo button under Push to Visual Studio Team Services.

   [image]
3. Verify your email and select your account in the Team Services Domain drop-down.
4. Enter your repository name and select Publish repository.

   [image]

This creates a new project in your account with the same name as the repository. To create the repo in an existing project, click Advanced next to Repository name and select a project.

5. Your code is now in a Git repo in Azure Repos. You can view your code on the web by selecting See it on the web.

   [image]

Comment: That's great, thanks. So I assume that, once the master is published, you should create a branch and work off of it. Is it correct that, in order to publish any new change, you have to: 1) Sync, 2) Commit, 3) Push?

Comment: You need commit and push, you can do these on the sync tab.

Comment: is this removed from the community edition?